# Laravel summernote in displaying

Tags: laravel

Guys I need your help,

In summer note I add text like this:
[summernote](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DS34s.png)

But this is what I get as a result:

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2KPG.png)

What I do to desplay the text is like below:

```
{{ str_limit(strip_tags($place->description), 150) }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blade provides default protection against html/css/js code injection so you should try to use `{!!`instead of `{{`. Moreover, the `strip_tags` function will remove all html tags, but summernote will save what you wrote as html, so it needs it to be displayed as html. I would try something like that :

```
{!! str_limit($place->description, 150) !!}
```

Let me know if it helped you :)